# Go doing or Go to do something

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

Is there a difference between

> "I am going cycling."

and

> "I am going to cycle."

Assuming that I'm at home right now and I'm informing everyone here that I'm leaving the house to do some cycling.

Further,

> "I'm going playing"
> or
> "I'm going to play"

> "I'm going bathing"
> or
> "I'm going to bathe"

This has been confusing me for quite a lot of time.

Is this different in British and American English?

Comment: I think I've seen this question on the ELU stack already. Give a look at the [search page](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Going+Vs+going+to), some entries might have your answer (or be helpful along with the answer Jesse just gave). Welcome to EL&U, anyhow. Cheers!

Comment: Also check out this similar question on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133182/going-to-present-simple-vs-going-to-present-continuous?r=SearchResults&s=6|85.5552

Comment: In many ways, it is more of an ELL Question. The reason it fits here pertains to whether one use may be more or less fitting for a given circumstance.

Comment: 'Be going to' can be looked up separately. 'I'm going to fast for 3 days' = 'I intend to fast for 3 days'. // 'Go V-ing' is often a phase structure: 'I'm going shopping' / 'She went dancing' / cf 'He sat knitting' / 'She's gone fishing' ..... Both questions already covered in depth on ELU. I’m voting to close this question.

Comment: It confuses writing with pronunciation (gonna is not going to), doubl-ing, future tense, purpose infinitives, and serial verbs. That's pretty confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your question's body asks about two constructions, but its title asks about two different ones --- to express the latter in terms of cycling: "I go cycling" and "I go to do cycling". Now "I go to do cycling" is not idiomatic (at least I can't think of any context where it would be the idiomatic thing to say). So let's consider:

1. I go cycling.
2. I am going cycling.
3. I am going to cycle.

One issue here is that there are two sorts of activity mentioned here. There's "cycling", the ordinary verb for riding a bicycle, and "going cycling", which has the connotation of riding a bicycle as a leisure or exercise activity.

One way to talk about things happening in the future is to use a construction "(be) going to (verb)" where the verb is in the infinitive. For example: Prices are going to rise. It's going to rain.

Sentence 3, "I am going to cycle.", is best understood as having this construct. So it's not about "going cycling", it's about plain "cycling". You might use it in a context like this.

A: I'll need to go to XTown tomorrow.

B: Are you going to drive?

C: No, I am going to cycle.

This construction always uses the words "going to", and doesn't use the verb's "-ing" form. Therefore sentences 1 and 2 above are not using this construction. Rather, they are talking about "going cycling" as a leisure or exercise activity. "I go cycling" indicates that you do it habitually. "I am going cycling" indicates that you are planning to do it some time in the future.

Answer (score -1):

## It's up to you.

This is a Question about gerunds vs infinitives, specifically whether an occasion calls for one, the other, or either.

From [EC](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/gerund-vs-infinitive-practice):

> **Gerunds** are often used when actions are real, fixed, or completed. *"I enjoy cooking."*
>
> **Infinitives** are often used when actions are unreal, abstract, or future: *"He wants to swim."*

Sometimes, it is about right and wrong grammar.

From [Ginger](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds-infinitives/):

> Knowing the difference between gerund and infinitive can save you from making costly grammar mistakes when writing.

But, that's not the case with your examples. All of your examples are grammatically correct. And no, this is not any major difference between British and American English. Any difference would be about habits, not spellings or common sayings.

## Which nuance do you want?

The *-ing* ending will communicate a continuous action, as if you will be doing this for a prolonged period of time. The infinitive *(to ___)* views it as a complete, whole, single event.

**Gerunds** from [Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/comparing_gerunds_participles_and_infinitives.html):

> With many of the verbs that follow the object, the use of the gerund indicates continuous action while the use of the simple verb indicates a one-time action.

**Infinitives** from [Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/infinitives.html):

> therefore expresses action or a state of being.

There isn't a difference in definition, and each can be rightly used to describe the other. As the artist using these words, you need to decide whether you want to portray this as a **continuous event** (-ing) or a **singular event** (to ___).

The difference is minimal at most. You could use either.